# Subsonic 2.2 Generated Property for SQL Server 2008 Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, subsonic

Im using latest SVN 2.2 build compiled with VS 2008.
When I build my VB classes using Sonic.exe any columns of type **Date** (Not **Datetime**) are generated as "System.String".
Has anybody else found this problem and have a solution or is this a problem with Subsonic?

Comment: Are you confirming this to be a problem?
I will gladly submit an issue, but I'd rather not add it to the issue stack needlessly. It seems to me that this is such a "base" issue that others must be experiencing it, yet I dont see any other reports.

Comment: This is still a problem, a 2008 date ticket was closed but this only seemed to affect datetime2 and not date or time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/list

Comment: Are you confirming this to be a problem? I will gladly submit an issue, but I'd rather not add it to the issue stack needlessly. It seems to me that this is such a "base" issue that others must be experiencing it, yet I dont see any other reports. – Zapatta 46 secs ago

Answer (score 2):

It's still a pending issue, but it's an easy fix.  If you have the SubSonic source code, make a few edits.

-- src\SubSonic\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider.cs.
Around line #1010 above "case datetime" add:

```
            case "date":
                return DbType.Date;
```

-- src\SubSonic\ActiveRecord\AbsractList.cs
Around line #85 above "else if (dbType == DbType.DateTime)" add:

```
        else if (dbType == DbType.Date)
        {
            DateTime dX = Convert.ToDateTime(xVal);
            DateTime dY = Convert.ToDateTime(yVal);
            result = dX.CompareTo(dY);
        }
```

-- src\SubSonic\CodeLanguage\CSharpCodeLanguage.cs
Around line #222 above "case DbType.DateTime" add:

```
            case DbType.Date:
```

I'm 99% these were the main changes needed, without these changes the last release will not properly support the SQL Server 2008 "DATE" data type.